# Authentication with Supabase and NextJS - getSession returns null at first, which leads to incorrect content rendering

Tags: authentication, next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-js

I'm using supabase-js v2 for authentication inside a NextJS project. On page load/reload i always see a login page (for 2 seconds before render the correct component) even if a user is logged.

The problem in with getSession returns null at first which leads to incorrect content rendering.

This is my AuthContext:

```
export const AuthProvider = ({
    children,
    sessionFromServer,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    sessionFromServer: Session | null;
}) => {
    const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | undefined>();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | undefined>();

    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getActiveSession() {
            const { data: { session: activeSession },} = await supabase.auth.getSession();
            setSession(activeSession ?? undefined);
            setUser(activeSession?.user ?? undefined);
        }

        getActiveSession();

        const { data: { subscription: authListener } } =
                        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, currentSession) => {
              setSession(currentSession!);
              setUser(currentSession?.user ?? undefined);

              if (currentSession?.access_token !== sessionFromServer?.access_token) {
                router.refresh();
              }
                });

        return () => { authListener?.unsubscribe(); };
    }, []);

    const value = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          session,
          user          
        };
    }, [session, user]);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
    }
    return context;
};
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Use server side rendering and something like [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) to determine what UI components need to be rendered conditionally before the user ever sees the page.

Comment: You can use the Supabase Next.js auth helpers to determine the auth state on server side. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs